# What 4-letter word am I?

Tags: riddle, word

Change my 1st, I'm quite a leaper.
Change my 2nd, I'm something extra.
Change my 3rd, I'm a heavy weapon.
Change my 4th, I differ in color.

**What 4-letter word am I?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are a

> MARE

Change my 1st, I'm quite a leaper.

> **H**ARE, a rabbit

Change my 2nd, I'm something extra.

> M**O**RE

Change my 3rd, I'm a heavy weapon.

> [MA**C**E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mace_(club)), a heavy metal club

Change my 4th, I differ in color.

> [MAR**K**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mark?s=t), a spot or line on a surface, visible through difference in color or elevation from that of the surrounding area. *Definition from link at Dictionary.com*

Comment: Ah, give it to him.

Comment: Ah, but @JLee:  Roland, although slower to actually answer the entire question, has made his answer more complete, in the end.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain The first to get the 4th part correct will get the check mark.

Comment: @JLee Marl? Mark? Not sure on the "differ in color" then...

Comment: @JLee See edit .

Comment: @JLee Mark? Making HOCK from the changed letters.

Comment: @JLee, I think Roland has it.  Just found the same thing.  [Marl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marl) can be many different colours.

Comment: @GordonK their main answer is correct. just trying to get part 4

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain it's not marl. it's straight from the word's definition, and fits better than marl or marx or mars, in my opinion

Comment: There are plenty of interpretations of "mark" which fit also, but I'm not sure any fit *better* than those already suggested.

Comment: @JLee Frankly, of all the options possible, I think MARL is the best fit, although none really seem like a great match.  I've gone through every letter of the alphabet and found nothing that would make me think "differ in colour" as the "definition" of the word.

Comment: @JLee Seems like you could have picked a better definition if it's proving this difficult to find the "correct" word.  There are many MAR* words with many definitions that would seem to work better.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain the actual definitions of MARS, MARX, and MARL have nothing to do with "differing in color" but [the actual definition of mark](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+mark&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) does. That is why I thought it fit better. way better even. Either way, you still got the correct answer. The only reason #4 mattered so much was that I needed a way to decide which of the 2 of your answers would be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: @JLee For me, "mark" is used so broadly to relate to any symbol, goal, or change in texture, depth, brightness, that "differ in color" is really only saying "is visible". Only after 50+ alternative definitions does Dictionary.com refer to color specifically, under medical definitions. What you call "the actual definition" can't even be found in most dictionaries, like [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mark) and [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mark), which means your particular description may have been too obscure.

Comment: @Roland Dictionary.com is not the authority. Google uses [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mark). Which of the other words include anything about color in their definitions, whether it be definition 1 or definition 99 in whatever dictionary you'd like to use? Is there any other that includes differing in color in its definition? If not, then I don't see the grounds that there were other alternatives that fit better. In reality, all either of you needed to solve the puzzle anyway was contained in the first 2 clues. Maybe I should have left it at that.

Answer (score 10):

You are

> **MARE**

Change my 1st, I'm quite a leaper.

> HARE

Change my 2nd, I'm something extra.

> MORE

Change my 3rd, I'm a heavy weapon.

> MACE

Change my 4th, I differ in color.

> <strike>MARS</strike>

Comment: not what i had in mind for the 4th